# Why to make the android application of my Website?

Tags: android

My website can easily be accessed through the mobile browsers .. but I want to develop an android app to provide more flexibility to the android users but what point make it different so, that, I should proceed to build an android app of my Website ?

Comment: Why won't you just use the mobile version of your site with Anrdoid's browser?

Comment: I only want to know that what make user more comfortable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your website provides services that are useful to the end users, then u definitely can develop an app. But, if ur website is just showing some information(which is not really useful to end user) you can just have ur website of mobile version. Because no user downloads the app from android market to read text or some images which r not useful to him.

Comment: services mean's can you give example of those service which can be provided only through android device but not through website...

Comment: something that is useful to end user. for example, mobile version of facebook website does not allow user to chat online. but facebook app allows it to do. If the user want to chat with his friends he definitely searches for an app in android market that allows him to chat with his friends. Offcourse u can make website that supports all the features, but to make it user friendly u need an app

Comment: ok but in window mobile I have seen that through the website also we can do chat... anyway thank's for your view.. really appreciate..

Comment: i have just given u example whats the useful service to the end user

Answer (score 1):

Many of the important point is mention above.. some important point that I have notice are :-

1. Application can be run if the internet cannot be access.
2. For making the operation automatic.. eg. uploading photo when internet is not accessible,  which can be synchronized later.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to do anything to Android Device, whatever you will be having on your live web site, you can easily access in the Android Device or any other device which has Internet Connection.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the type of contents.

There are some questions.

If it is organization news/updates for public, who are the reader/who will be interested in it?

If it is for public, twitter/fb/google+ are the better ways for releasing news, and redirect to your website.

Application is needed when you need special permissions from the mobile device, e.g. GPS location for check-in, releasing coupon, take photo and upload/share, easier account integration, etc. Otherwise, a mobile version website is enough.